# Microphone BufferReady event handler doesnt get in windows phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i have the following code in Windows Phone 8 App:

```
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        microphone = Microphone.Default;
        microphone.BufferReady += Device_BufferReady;
        bStarted = true;
        tbData.Text = "00:00:00";
        m_lDuration = 0;
        microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        baBuffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(microphone.BufferDuration)];
        microphone.Start();
```

however Device_BufferReady never gets hit! any idea what im doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you getting null in microphone object? Please check it once and if u r getting null then please add `ID_CAP_MICROPHONE` capability to your project

Comment: no not really I`m not getting null , and yes the Microphone capability is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the sample code provided on the dev center (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Microphone-Sample-b2ebe8b6) makes use of a ticker with a 33ms period, from which you call the FrameworkDispatcher.Update() method...

```
        // Timer to simulate the XNA Framework game loop (Microphone is 
        // from the XNA Framework). We also use this timer to monitor the 
        // state of audio playback so we can update the UI appropriately.
        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);
        dt.Tick += delegate { try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); } catch { } };
        dt.Start();
```

Did you implement this?

Comment: weird thing is i implemented this instead 
 public class XNAFrameworkDispatcherService : IApplicationService
but it didnt fix the problem, however your solution did !